# How prevalent was premarital sex in Late Medieval Christendom?

Tags: middle-ages, sexuality, bohemia, czech-republic

A few months, I very much enjoyed a playthrough of the video game ***Kingdom Come: Deliverance***, which is set within the borders of what was then the **Kingdom of Bohemia** during the Western Schism (1378 - 1417). Video games are, of course, never a great source for a serious historian; the primary focus of any games designer worth his salt must be on what is fun, and not necessarily on what actually happened. But, for all that, *Kingdom Come: Deliverance* has earned a reputation for an unusual fidelity to history - at least by yardstick of other games. Indeed, it awoke an interest in my own heart for Late Medieval Central Europe that I never knew I had.

One of the subplots of the game involves a romance between the player character, Henry, and his wily young friend, Theresa. Both characters are **unmarried**, perhaps in their late teens, from **one of the lower rungs of the feudal hierarchy**. Following a brief courtship, the two make love, and, while it is half-implied that this may be Henry's first time, it is clearly not Theresa's. Afterwards, when Henry tentatively broaches the topic of marriage, Theresa replies that she would like to get married one day, perhaps to him, but she has no intention of marrying for the foreseeable future.

I was curious as to how likely this series of events would have been, in the place and time in which the game is set? It seemed to reflect more modern attitudes to sex than medieval ones, but perhaps these are more constant throughout history than I had imagined?

In terms of **qualitative data**, I suppose I'm looking for things like sermons along the lines of "Look how widespread fornication is these days!" Or maybe even a seduction manual from the period, some kind of Late Medieval update on Ovid's *Ars Amatoria*? In terms of **quantitative data**, perhaps an estimate on the proportion of babies born to unmarried mothers would be a good start? Although the game is in Bohemia, I would be interested to read about data from any country in Central or Western Europe in the Late Middle Ages; prove me wrong by all means, but I can't imagine that attitudes would differ radically between Roman Catholic countries in that period.

Comment: BBC History did an article five or six years ago discussing a methodology for answering a similar question about Victorian London. The results wouldn't help, but the methodology might.   From memory, I think you're on the right track. ( I personally suspect that premarital sex was ubiquitous.)

Comment: Pre-marital or pre-betrothal? Betrothal was sometimes the important step, not the wedding itself.

Comment: Notoriously, betrothals and marriages were easy to confuse in the day.  In particular, in medieval times, even if you used the future tense (normally indicating a betrothal) and had intercourse, you were, in fact, married.

Comment: @Mary: That's patently false. Consider the circumstances of *William the Bastard*, later to be known as *William the Conqueror* (the latter no doubt encouraged by William in preference to the former), and of [Thomas Moreton FitzHardinge Berkeley](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/70268/prior-to-1963-did-a-british-nobleman-ever-disclaim-or-renounce-his-title-what-w/70270#70270) who inherited the title due to his four elder brothers by the same mother all being illegitimate.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens  What is the relevance of your claim to what I said?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Both the cases you mention concerned a nobleman and a woman of much lower status. In the case of the Earl of Berkeley, his father deliberately tricked a young woman  into a bogus marriage, then later decided to legalise the union because he had grown to love her.

Comment: Because of the lack of reliable contraception, it would be a reckless woman who slept with a man without having (or hoping for) the option of marrying him in case of pregnancy.

Comment: Given the answer to a related but easier question regarding [19th century England](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/51423/what-was-the-rate-of-premarital-conceptions-in-england-from-1850-to-1890) I strongly suspect this one is basically unanswerable.

Comment: @KateBunting I agree that, in the days before reliable contraception, female promiscuity would have been reckless. But young people - especially HORNY young people! - have a well-known taste for reckless behaviour. Such behaviour may have been reckless, but my question is: How UNUSUAL was it?

Comment: I can't "prove" it, but suspect it was pretty common. Young gentry/noble children left home to serve in higher status houses at an early age, sharing beds was normal, and I doubt if the average 13+ Yr old understood the consequences - or even the process - of illicit sex. And, historically, social disapproval has **rarely** stopped youngsters from "experimenting".

Comment: Put it this way, then - it was reckless of Theresa to dismiss the possibility of marriage without keeping her options open just in case!

Comment: @TheHonRose I don't think your understanding the consequences part is true historically. Anyone who grew up close to farm animals knows how human reproduction works by analogy and that meant everyone until the beginning of industrialization. I think the very concept of someone reaching adult age without knowing the connection between sex and pregnancy only appeared around 1800 or so.

Comment: @quarague Hmm I'm not too sure. I think there is quite a conceptual leap for a child/young person to see a stallion mount a mare, and having a kiss and cuddle *et al* behind the arras.